# Blackberry BIS Option secret key vs mds-public

Tags: blackberry

To use the BIS connection in blackberry, developers need to register for the BB alliance program. However the [site](https://partners.blackberry.com/web/guest/not-a-member) is no longer available to new members.

What is the "official" way to using BIS connection on blackberry now? Using mds-public  as the secret key works for me though but need to be sure this is standard.

```
connFact.setTransportTypeOptions(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B,
            new BisBOptions("mds-public"));
```

Comment: just this single line addition to use bis-b without all the hassles of registration. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood you will get access to BIS-B immediately as you registered for BB push. But I don't know if you could get it without push registration.

Comment: You can USE BISB connection without registering for PUSH.