# blackberry - sending pushapi registration request results in a connection timeout

Tags: blackberry

When I try this programmatically / in a browser, it times out. Any idea where I'm going wrong? My request looks like this -

http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_subReg?serviceid=myServiceId&osversion=5.0.0.436&model=9520

Comment: try in your device. The device should have an BIS connectivity.

Comment: @Signare how would I check that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770789/unable-to-connect-to-internet-in-blackberry-device/11772234#11772234

Comment: first activate blackberry internet service in ur device.