# Blackberry BrowserField error loading url

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I am using verticalfield manager to load data  and browserfield to load url but both are in the same screen.

I am just swapping both as per my need using **replace(field1,field2)**. But when i am trying to load url on bwoserfield, it can not load the url.

Anyone know how to resolve an issue.

Comment: see this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Browser-field-coul-not-load-a-url/td-p/1742819

Comment: please review this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770789/unable-to-connect-to-internet-in-blackberry-device/11772234#11772234

Comment: @Eugen Martynov : This issue reproducing in only OS7 and its working properly in OS6 and OS5.

Comment: Yup!!! Resolved the issue by re initiate the browserfield and load the url.

Comment: If you resolved then put the answer and give mark to your answer